# Locking support detected on remote "origin"

Tags: git, git-lfs

I started tracking some files with git-lfs.  Upon my next `git push`, I get constant (censored) message:

```
Locking support detected on remote "origin". Consider enabling it with:
  $ git config lfs.<repo_url>.git/info/lfs.locksverify true
```

When I run `git config lfs.<repo_url>.git/info/lfs.locksverify true`, the command exits with success and no output, and the same message continues to print with every `git push`.

Considering we have automation scripted around git output, how can I disable this message?  Will every git client using my repo now have to run the same remediation?

Comment: Strange that you get no output.  Have you tried restarting the Git bash after running the `git config` command?  Also, where/what is your remote Git repo?

Comment: I tried restarting my prompt to no avail.  My remote git is hosted by VSTS.  I've mitigated the issue by deleting and re-cloning the repo; however, I would still like to enable git-lfs without compromising our automation.

Comment: Just to make sure: did you replace the `<repo_url>` with actual repository url?

Comment: Indeed I replaced my hostname with `<repo_url>` when copying to stack overflow

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue; but I *do* want LFS locking enforced

Answer (score 1):

When you run `$ git config lfs.<repo_url>.git/info/lfs.locksverify true`, it added to your git workspace/local config file. when your re-clone the workspace, it is not present.

You can verify that by running `$ git config --list`

To avoid asking this every time, add that your global/system (`--global`) git config in the build machines.

`$ git config lfs.<repo_url>.git/info/lfs.locksverify true --global`